# Locating Tables via HtmlProvider

Tags: f#

I am using the FSharp.Data Html type provider on [this](http://services.wakegov.com/realestate/Account.asp?id=0000001) page.  I have loaded the body with this code:

```
#r "../packages/FSharp.Data.2.1.1/lib/net40/FSharp.Data.dll"
open FSharp.Data
type context = HtmlProvider<"../data/RealEstateSample.html">

let uri = "http://services.wakegov.com/realestate/Account.asp?id=0000001"
let body = context.Load(uri).Html.Body
```

The problem is that the body value (unit -> HtmlNode) does not return anything other than GetType() and ToString().  Am I missing an assembly ref?  I want to put all of the tables from the page into a collection.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so this was a brain fart.  Here is the correct syntax:

```
let body = context.Load(uri).Html.Body()
```

Body is a function...